# I'm trying to create an add in in C# to validate mailItem.Body to avoid an specific content, but my event doesn't activate when I send a message

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am trying to validate a specific text in the body of each email.  The code is running at session beginning, but it doesn't run when I send a message. How could I associate this code segment to the send event?

```
namespace OutlookAddIn2
{

public partial class ThisAddIn
{

    Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
        inspectors.NewInspector +=
        new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(ItemSend);

    }


      void ItemSend(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
        Outlook.NameSpace session = mailItem.Session;
        Outlook.Accounts accounts = session.Accounts;
        mailItem.SendUsingAccount = Application.Session.Accounts[1];

        if (mailItem.Body != null) //--- validate mail item is not empty
        {
            string strBody;
            string prompt;
            // ---inicialize variables
            strBody = mailItem.Body.ToUpper();
            //--- validate content
            if (strBody.Contains("SPECIAL TEXT"))
            {
                prompt = "This email look like content Special Text information. Do you want to send it anyway?";

                DialogResult result;

                result = MessageBox.Show(prompt, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                //-- give them chance to send it or not
                if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    mailItem.Send();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you never up set the `MailItem.Send` event handler.

Secondly, you don't need to - simply use `Application.ItemSend` event.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. This is my first try to program for outlook. Do you have any sample or guide to follow to do this. 
With your comments I found extra information and I could finish my add-in in Vb. I paste my code for future reference. Thanks again

Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
Imports Microsoft.Office.Tools

Public Class ThisAddIn

## Region "Class level declarations"

```
Private m_objOutlook As Outlook.Application
Private WithEvents m_objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

'Event-aware references to Explorers collection & ActiveExplorer
Private WithEvents m_colExplorers As Outlook.Explorers
Private WithEvents m_olExplorer As Outlook.Explorer

'Event-aware references to Inspectors collection & ActiveInspector
Private WithEvents m_colInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors
Private WithEvents m_olInspector As Outlook.Inspector
Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Dim Item As Object
'  Dim ol As OutlookHandler
Public Delegate Sub ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
```

## End Region

```
Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Startup
    ' Store a reference to the Outlook.Application object.
    m_objOutlook = Me.Application
    Items = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder.Items


    'Item = Items.Add()
    'Item.Display

    AddHandler m_objOutlook.ItemSend, AddressOf MyItemSendEventHandler



End Sub

Public Sub MyItemSendEventHandler(ByVal Item As Object, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)

    '--- this macro advice about confidential information in the content.
    '--- create variables to save message body and a counter of confidential words
    Dim strBody As String
    Dim intConfidential As Integer
    Dim prompt As String
    '--- inicialize variables
    strBody = UCase(Item.Body)
    intConfidential = InStr(1, strBody, "SPECIAL TEXT", 1)
    '--- validate content
    If intConfidential >= 1 Then
        prompt = "API: This email look like content confidential information. Do you want to send it anyway?"
        '-- givethem chance to sendit or not
        If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion + vbMsgBoxSetForeground, "Check Body Text") = vbNo Then
            Cancel = True
        End If
    End If

End Sub


Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown

End Sub
```